# Client connection to IBM MQ unauthorized

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to setup a Client connection to IBM MQ and test this using the samples application wmqjava.

I am able to connect in binding mode but I'm getting a 2035 unauthorised error when using client mode.

The steps I've taken to set this up are:

- Create / run a queue manager
- Create a listener
- Create a SVRConn channel (multiple attempts)

I think I'm missing something with authorisation?

```
DEF CHL('TEST2.CHANNEL') CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) MCAUSER(' ')
```

I'm trying to connect to this on the same machine that the MQ server is running on.

Comment: This is due to channel authorisation. Quick fix is to disable it on the queue manager alter qmgr chauth(disabled)

Comment: This *could* be CHLAUTH - but if he's on V8 it could also be CONNAUTH. The queue manager error log will have the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of IBM MQ you are using, you could be being blocked by the default CHLAUTH rule which bans client connections which assert privileged user ids, or the default CONNAUTH rule which demands a password is provided for such a client connection.

Read [Getting going without turning off MQ Security](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/middleware/viewdocument/from-the-archives-getting-going-wi) for instructions on how to turn both off, or use both correctly.

FYI: Your queue manager error log will tell you the reason you were blocked from accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the user "mqm" in MCAUSER Field to bypass all the authorisation.

**DEF CHL('TEST2.CHANNEL') CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) MCAUSER('mqm')**

This will use all the authorities of **mqm** user (Default MQ admin user) to connect to Queue Manager.
Alternatively you can authorize the user to allow to **connect**, **put**, **get** messages.

**setmqauth** or **getmqauth** commands can help you.

Comment: This won't work if CHLAUTH default rule to ban privileged users is still active. Also, no such thing as getmqauth. There is a setmqauth (note no 'h' on the end) and a dspmqaut.